# Sorting elements using insertion sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion

If I am using insertion sort as shown below and have an array with some elements that are integers and then some that are null - How would I go about sorting that array with the null elements at the end using insertion sort?

For example: [1, 2, 6, null, 9, 5, 4, null, 2, 3]
To: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, null, null]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to write a `compareTo` function that handles `null`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int compareTo(T a, T b)
{
    if (a == null && b == null) return 0;
    if (a == null) return 1;
    if (b == null) return -1;
    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

Then have the insertion sort use that:

```
while (compareTo >= 0 && compareTo(newElement, array[compareTo]) < 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with [`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void insertionSort(T[] array) {
    Comparator<T> comparator = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    // ...
    int compareTo = sorted;
    while (compareTo >= 0 && comparator.compare(newElement, array[compareTo]) < 0) {
    // ...
}
```

I converted the `Comparable` comparison criteria into a `Comparator` using [`Comparator.naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()).